# Limit to the number of times you can edit a question?

Tags: discussion, editing

I have noticed that many users change the entire context of the question based on a certain comment, and this invalidates the answer provided by a different user.

Is there a limit to the number of times one can edit a question? Specifically the title of the question? or the KEY QUESTION that is being asked?

I understand that editing the code/reproducible examples for the question should be allowed numerous times, as long as the entire question does not become a different question altogether.

Link to a question that I had asked and was edited by me multiple times, until I realized that the answer lies is in a different approach (thereby changing the title itself).

[Calculate Proportion of Land Cover Classes with a moving window around a point in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/236337/calculate-proportion-of-land-cover-classes-with-a-moving-window-around-a-point-i)

A different case where questions are edited based on comments received, but the overall ask slightly changes each time:

[Same extent and resolution of rasters, but different number of cells](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/231165/same-extent-and-resolution-of-rasters-but-different-number-of-cells)

Comment: Do you have a link or two to the questions that have been edited many times?

Comment: Included questions that I personally edited multiple times.

Comment: What do you mean by "the KEY QUESTION that is being asked"?  There should only ever be one question asked per question as per the [Tour].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I haven't found anything official, however a look around Meta SO and Meta SE netted a few Q&As regarding edit limits on questions.  **It appears there may be a limit of 5 edits, however this is on older questions** (more than a day or two old).  This limit is there primarily to prevent rage-quitting and vandalism.  See [Should the 5 edit limit prevent you from hitting edit in the first place?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125372/should-the-5-edit-limit-prevent-you-from-hitting-edit-in-the-first-place).

I think edit limits would cause problems if applied to new questions, as often edits need to be made to get questions re-opened after being put On Hold, or in response to comments asking for more information or clarification.  If there were a limit I think we'd end up with more questions left closed, and the asker just re-asking in a new question, or abandoning the site altogether.  We want to avoid this!

On the flip side, as a community we need to ensure that edits are *improving* the question rather than *changing* it.  It is unfair on our volunteers to spend time writing up an excellent answer only to find the question is significantly changed, and even potentially attract downvotes for not answering the question.

I believe that as a moderator I have reviewed automatic flags when a question has been edited too many times, but I'm not 100% sure on that.  I do check edits to make sure the focus isn't changing too much, and have occasionally suggested that a new question should be asked and that the good answers upvoted/accepted on the original question where appropriate.

Comment: +1 I have reviewed many automatic flags that are raised at 20 edits.  (Yes, some questions get edited that much!)

Answer (score 2):

I think it is worth mentioning the **Editing** section from the [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide):

> **Editing**
>
> - 5 edits on one's own posts per day, more for high-rep users (scales with reputation), does not apply to ♦ mods
>
> > You have already edited 5 of your own post today; further edits are
> >     not allowed until tomorrow
>
> - 5 deleted old answers per day (not sure if this is counted along with edits or separately, confirm/refute), does not apply to ♦ mods
> - At most 5 pending suggested edits per editor (20 on beta sites)
> - Unregistered Users can't suggest edits on posts < 10 minutes old
> - Users with < 10k rep trip Captcha if more than once per 30 seconds, or faster than 5 seconds after starting edit
> - Users with > 10k rep trip Captcha if more than once per 10 seconds, or faster than 5 seconds after starting edit
> - You can only save a tag wiki edit once every 30 seconds.

The only other editing "limit" that I know of, mentioned in a [comment by @whuber](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4541/limit-to-the-number-of-times-you-can-edit-a-question#comment8282_4542), is that a flag to moderators is raised when a question has been edited more than 20 times.  I have not been able to find this documented but I think it is there to detect users who are performing trivial edits to bump their question to the home page.  Such behaviour [can be met with suspension](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294651/does-frequently-editing-questions-with-proper-reason-lead-to-suspension), but here at GIS SE, as far as I know, we have always clicked away that flag, because in all instances that I have seen the edits have seemed reasonable (usually on Community Wiki posts).

I think any editing that improves, even quite modestly, the chances of a question being answered or acting as a better example for questions by new users (so they get theirs answered quicker), is worth doing.

The edits to avoid are those which strand/invalidate an answer by changing the question (that has already been answered) too much.  Those edits should be rolled back and comment made to suggest that a new question be asked.

Remember that Q&A is not designed to be a discussion between askers and answerers on how to solve a problem.  On the other hand askers can get great insight into how to solve their problems by asking focussed questions that break larger problems into answerable chunks (in separate focussed Q&As).

Comment: This is very very interesting. Thanks @PolyGeo